# How to display ActionLink with | symbol

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I want to create a group of Actionlink and have control on that. Like

Add | Edit | Delete

I tried it as

> ```
> grid.Column(header: "Payload Actions", format:         
>         @<text>
>             @if (item.Status == "ERROR")
>             {
>                 @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", "THRecovery", new {item.id}, new {@class = "addAction", @style = "color:blue;"}) |
>                 @Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", "THRecovery", new {item.id}, new {@class = "detailAction", @style = "color:blue;"}) |
>                 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "THRecovery", new { item.id }, new { @class = "deleteAction", @style = "color:blue;" })
>             }             
>              @if (item.Status != "ERROR")
>             {
>                 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "THRecovery", new {item.id}, new {@class = "detailAction", @style = "color:blue;"})
>             }                
>          </text>
>      )
> ```

I added "|" at the end of ActionLink but it is giving me error - Unexpected Token.

If status = ERROR then I want to display as   Add | Detail | Delete
if not then only Detail

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you put '|' inside a `<text>` tag.

Like this:

```
<text>|</text>
```

Exemple with your code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", "THRecovery", new {item.id}, new {@class = "addAction", @style = "color:blue;"}) <text>|</text>
```

You can use `@:|` too. This way the pipe character will be read as server code and will print the '|' character without any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer